# Search "bcd" with exclusion of "abcd" using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I need to search one key word, for example, "bcd" or "BCD"; but want to exclude the result of "abcd".

How could I use regex to accomplish this?

What I found on this site now is matching everything but excluding one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this,

```
(?i)(?:^|[^a])bcd
```

You may play with it here,

https://regex101.com/r/jp0lqF/4

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex,

```
(?<!a|A)(bcd|BCD)
```

This will match a bcd, not after 'a'

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jp0lqF/2)